# Sharepoint: Sharepoint custom list validation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Can anybody tell me how we write validation formula for "single line of text" fields in SharePoint list  that it accepts characters only.

Comment: this belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think without SP Designer is this not possible. There are following functions available:
ISBLANK ISERR ISERROR ISLOGICAL ISNA ISNONTEXT ISNULL ISNUMBER ISTEXT
See this reference:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/is-functions-HA100405908.aspx

Answer (score 0):

JQuery to the rescue again I'd have thought: I use this this type of entry in forms where I want to constrain input values:

```
    $('input[title="MyColumnName"]').keyup(function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<%@ language="C#" %>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                        ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                        ControlToValidate="txtName"     
                                        ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" />
    </form>
```